# Script fails to extract certain fields from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape `title`, `website` and `email` from this [webpage](https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13153157-azajola-stare-mesto-nova-seninka.html). The content available in there are heavily dynamic. Although `requests` module can't handle javascript heavy content, there are always alternatives to grab the same using the very library, as in using any external link retrieved from dev tools. However, I just can't find the right way to do the trick.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13153157-azajola-stare-mesto-nova-seninka.html'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    title = soup.select_one("h1").text
    website = soup.select_one("a.companyUrl").text
    email = soup.select_one("a.companyMail").text
    print(title,website,email)
```

When I run the script above, it throws `AttributeError`.

Output that I'm after:

```
AZAJOLA, s.r.o., www.chatanovaseninka.cz, info@chatanovaseninka.cz
```

PS I don't wish to go for any browser simulator like selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site uses `FastRPC` protocol (which is additionally encoded with Base64). You can install `PyFRPC` module from https://pypi.org/project/pyfrpc/ to encode/decode the messages:

```py
import re
import pyfrpc  # <-- install from https://pypi.org/project/pyfrpc/
import base64
from pprint import pprint

url = (
    "https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13153157-azajola-stare-mesto-nova-seninka.html"
)
api_url = "https://www.firmy.cz/RPC2/"
id_ = int(re.search(r"detail/(\d+)", url).group(1))

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/x-base64-frpc",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-base64-frpc",
}
c = pyfrpc.FrpcCall(
    name="system.multicall",
    args=[
        [
            {
                "methodName": "detail.getDetail",
                "params": [
                    {"version": "1.0"},
                    id_,
                    {"searchInCategory": False, "deliveryNetwork": ""},
                ],
            },
            {
                "methodName": "review.listReviews",
                "params": [{"version": "1.0"}, id_, 0, 3],
            },
        ]
    ],
)
msg_to_send = base64.b64encode(pyfrpc.encode(c, 0x0201))

r = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=msg_to_send)
response = pyfrpc.decode(base64.b64decode(r.text))

# uncomment to see all data:
# pprint(response.data)

print(response.data[0]["result"]["title_web"])
print(response.data[0]["result"]["email"])
print(response.data[0]["result"]["url"].split("#")[0])
```

Prints:

```
AZAJOLA, s.r.o.
info@chatanovaseninka.cz
http://www.chatanovaseninka.cz
```